# Passing int from activity to fragment using getArguments() always returns 0

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've looked at countless other post to see try and get this working with no luck unfortunately, so here goes.

I'm passing 4 variables from an activity to a dialog fragment. 3 int's and a string. The String value succeeds but the int's are always set to zero. The string is received from another class that implements Parcelable.

```
static final String P1_ROUDN_WINS = "user1RWins";
static final String P2_ROUDN_WINS = "user2RWins";
static final String NUM_ROUNDS = "numberOfRounds";
static final String PLAYER_NAME = "winnersName";
```

Activity

```
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(P1_ROUDN_WINS, p1RoundWins);
bundle.putInt(P2_ROUDN_WINS, p2RoundWins);
bundle.putInt(NUM_ROUNDS, numLegs);
bundle.putString(PLAYER_NAME, newPlayers.get(currentPlayer -1).getPlayerName());
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
GamerOverDialog dialogFragment = new GamerOverDialog ();
                dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                dialogFragment.show(fm, "Game Over");
```

Fragment

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rWins = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numWinTV);
    rLose = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numLoseTV);
    rounds = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numRoundsTV);
    name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playerNameTV);
    Log.i("Game over dialog: " , getArguments().getInt(Scoreboard.P1_ROUDN_WINS)+" wins");
    String roundWins = ""+ getArguments().getInt(Scoreboard.P1_ROUDN_WINS);
    String roundLose = ""+ getArguments().getInt(Scoreboard.P2_ROUDN_WINS);
    String numLegs = ""+ getArguments().getInt(Scoreboard.NUM_ROUNDS);
    String winnersName = "" + getArguments().getString(Scoreboard.PLAYER_NAME);
    rWins.setText(roundWins);
    rLose.setText(roundLose);
    rounds.setText(numLegs);
    name.setText(winnersName);
}
```

I know there's other similar posts but nothing I try works. Any help understanding what I'm doing wrong would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that the keys PLAYER_NAME, P1_ROUDN_WINS, P2_ROUDN_WINS, and NUM_ROUNDS are all different? Otherwise you'd be replacing them every time you set one.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question but here they are. 'static final String P1_ROUDN_WINS = "user1RWins";
    static final String P2_ROUDN_WINS = "user1RWins";
    static final String NUM_ROUNDS = "numberOfRounds";
    static final String PLAYER_NAME = "winnersName"; '

Comment: You could pass them as strings then parse them when you receive them; if what you are doing is not working

Comment: I tried that already and it has the same effect. :-(

Comment: You may want to log or output the contents of the arguments both before you're setting the arguments, and in onViewCreated, just as a sanity check to ensure all the values you set are there, and that the keys for those arguments are identical. If the arguments themselves look good in both places, I'd next try looking at the keys you're using for retrieval. You're using Scoreboard constants in your fragment, but when you set the arguments, you're using constants in your activity. If Scoreboard is not the activity, then maybe the keys aren't the same.

Comment: @Kden you're using "user1RWins" for two keys - meaning P2_ROUDN_WINS will *replace* P1_ROUDN_WINS.

Comment: @SamDozor I spotted that and changed it. That's not the issue though unfortunately.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I looked over it and couldn't find the problems. So I decided to follow Googles tutorial here [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html] and it's working now. Thanks for the help guys, much appreciated.